# Get the top N records from two unconnected data sets

Tags: ruby, sorting, pagination

I have two Rails services that return data from distinct databases. In one data set I have records with fields that are something like this:

```
query, clicks, impressions
```

In the second I have records with fields something like this:

```
query, clicks, visitors
```

What I want to be able to do, is get paged data from the merged set, matching on queries. But it needs to also include all records that exist in one or the other data sets, and then sort them by the 'clicks' column.

In SQL if these two tables were in the same database I'd do this:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(a.query, b.query), a.clicks, b.clicks, impressions, visitors 
FROM a OUTER JOIN b ON a.query = b.query 
LIMIT 100 OFFSET 1 
ORDER BY MAX(a.clicks, b.clicks)
```

An individual "top 100" to each data set produces incorrect results because 'clicks' in data set 'a' may be significantly higher or lower than in dataset 'b'.

As they aren't in the same database, I'm looking for help with the algorithm that makes this kind of query efficient and clean.

Comment: Are you using ActiveRecord to query your databases?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ActiveRecord. Although I'm not sure that's relevant. The services are connected with HTTP/JSON.

Comment: @jwadsack I guess this SO answer might be of some help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186682/access-merge-two-databases-with-identical-structure

Comment: @jwadsack Other lengthy option can be to merge merge AR collections from both the databases using iteration and union based on conditions.

Comment: @AlokAnand The SO answer you point to involved Access which can read two databases. Our data sets are millions of records of which we want pages of 100 (usually only the first). Access isn't an option. We could use the existing database (PostgreSQL in both cases) but that violates our SOA separation. Merging the records in ruby is also possible (The SOA interface doesn't have an AR connector, but, again, I don't think that's relevant.) Based on other data processing code, I also don't think that's tenable for the scale of the data set.

Comment: Also, to be clear, if we do merge records in ruby (or something that's not a database), is there an algorithm you can point to that makes this rapid?

Comment: Is it possible to take 100 records from each database, join them, sort and then filter first 100 from the resulting 200-records set?

Comment: That doesn't quite work (I tried this). If you choose top 100 records from each set, sorted, that doesn't match the top 100 (or 200) records of the combined set when merged and sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a way to do this outside of a database. In the end, we just used PostgreSQL's Foreign Data Wrapper feature to connect the two databases together and use PostgreSQL for handling the sorting and paging.

One trick for anyone heading down this path, we built VIEWs on the remote server that provided exactly the data needed in `a` above. This was thousands of times faster than trying to join tables across the remote connection as the value of the indexes was lost.